# How to offset a text by half of its height to center it vertically by an angle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I noticed that my text is a bit offset, which is only notable when the spacing is limited. It is supposed to be centered (which it is wrt its baseline) but it makes it look shifted upwards when the spacing happens to be smaller than usual.

This is an example of it: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/oc3u2v6e/). A very obvious occurence is if one clicks on the red category, number 5. Then, the most most yellow field is too narrow to harbor the text as it looks now.

```
var txt = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(30).outerRadius(90);

grx.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + txt.centroid(d) + ")"
      + "rotate(" + getRotation(d) + ")"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; });

function getRotation(d) {
  var angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / Math.PI * 90 + 90;
  return angle < 90 || angle > 270 ? angle : angle - 180;
}
```

How can I offset the text by an angle corresponding to the half of the height of the rendered text? Is it insanely difficult?

Comment: Use `getBBox` to find the svg element's height and width and then use `transform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [`dy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy) attribute to translate the text to the bottom. To shift it downwards [half its height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems) this value should be `0.5em`. Looking at the output this seems too much, though, using `0.3em` looks more pleasing to the eye.

```
grx.append("text")
  .attr("class", "legendMain")
  .attr("text-anchor", getAnchor)
  .attr("dy", "0.3em")   // Move downwards 30 percent its height
```

See this update [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvwd4b5s/1/) for a working example.

Comment: Indeed, it looks proper and nice. Just two follow-up questions. (1) Are we actually **rotating** the text here by a small degree or just **pushing** it vertically downwards? (For small angles, the difference is negligible, so it's not a critique - just curiosity, since I can't tell by just seeing the effect.) (2) Why 30%? Is it an arbitrary amount that seems to do the job or is there a "rule" that the text gets 30% raise that we need to counter-act on?

Comment: (1) This is pushing it downwards. The rotation is entirely caused by the `transform="rotate()"` you are applying to rotate the text. (2) My first try was to set it to `0.5` as you requested *"How to offset a text by **half of its height**"*. That didn't look right though, thus I eyeballed it to `0.3em`, i. e. 30% its height.